# Minimal polynomial of Galois extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K$ be a Galois extension of $F$ and let $a\in K$. Let $n=[K:F]$, $r=[F(a):F]$ and $H=Gal(K/F(a))$. Let $\tau_{1},\dots,\tau_{r}$ be left coset representatives of $H$ in $G$. Show that $\min(F,a) = \prod_{i=1}^{r}\left(x-\tau_{i}\left(a\right)\right)$. 
Conclude that $\prod_{\sigma\in Gal(K/F)}\left(x-\sigma\left(a\right)\right)=\min\left(F,a\right)^{n/r}$.

Help me a hint. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Sorry, it's duplicated.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110122/minimal-polynomial-of-intermediate-extensions-under-galois-extensions?rq=1